# Verification of http:// or https:// in an argument with grep in Bash

Tags: bash, grep

```
Input = ./q4.sh https://cdn.eso.org/images/thumb700x/eso1723a.jpg

echo $1 | -Eiq '^https?://' 2> /dev/null || echo 'Ce script supporte seulement les URLs commencant par https:// ou http://' && exit 1
```

The output always jumps to the last `|| echo 'Ce script supporte seulement les URLs commencant par https:// ou http://'` even if my argument 1 have http:// or https://.

Comment: I cant use if/fi or any other command then echo/grep and I have to redirect my stderr to /dev/null

Comment: no need for 2 separate greps. Just a simple regex is enough: `https?://`

Comment: Like this ? 

echo $1 | grep -i "https?://" $1 2> /dev/null || echo 'Ce script supporte seulement les URLs commencant par https:// ou http://' && exit 1

Because it keep sending me to the last || option even if my arg1 have https:// or http://

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to `grep` or even `bash`'s regular expression matching, you can use pattern matching.

```
if [[ $1 != http?(s)://* ]]; then
```

Answer (score 3):

This may set you on the right path

```
echo "$1" | grep -Eiq '^https?://' 2>/dev/null || echo "fail"
```

Comment: you don't need `2 >/dev/null`. Just use `grep -Eq` for regex and quiet mode

Comment: Yup that's great suggestion.
GOY1M could use that and leave a note for their professor indicating why they chose that over piping to /dev/null

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help! Now I change it for
echo $1 | grep -Eq "https?://" $1 || echo 'Ce script supporte seulement les URLs commencant par https:// ou http://' && exit 1

But it output this grep: https://cdn.eso.org/images/thumb700x/eso1723a.jpg: No such file or directory

Comment: @G0Y1M it's because of the last `$1`. Please read the command carefully. Compare this with yours

Answer (score 2):

Assuming without loss of generality your script is called with one argument which is `http://something`:

`echo $1 | grep -i "http://" $1` does not look for `http://` in the string `http://something` which was output by `echo` to the pipe, because `grep option(s) regexp argument` ignores its stdin and instead reads the file *named by* the argument. Thus it tries to read *a file named `http://something`* which of course does not exist. But since you've redirected `2>/dev/null` the error message that would tell you this disappears, so you just get the message complaining about the URL and exit.

Doing `echo $1 | grep -i "http://"` (and similarly for https) would work, but is very clumsy. It also outputs the (matched) URL to stdout, which you *didn't* redirect, so it will probably appear on your terminal, which may or may not be what you want. In general you should use `echo "$1" ...` whenever the argument could contain whitespace (or other IFS delimiter) or any wildcard (glob) character(s), but a valid URL cannot do the first and almost never does the last so in this specific case it's less important.

Also that grep *will* match and thus accept a URL that *contains* http:// or https:// but does not *begin with* it, as the echo message states is required. If you want to match only at the beginning, use `^` in the regexp.

A more efficient solution would be a single grep (with `^https?` in Extended mode meaning 'either http or https but only at beginning') with input from a herestring:

```
grep -Ei "^https?://" <<<$1 || echo "URL must begin ..." && exit 1
# if you don't want the matched URL output on stdout, 
# either redirect [1]>/dev/null or add q to the options (-Eiq)
```

Even more efficient (no grep at all) if you can settle for lowercase-only (which in practice is what people always use for URL schemes, even if the standard says uppercase should be accepted) is:

```
case $1 in (http://* https://*) ;; (*) echo "URL must begin ..." ... ; esac
```

Comment: This is my full script. with your indication, it fixes my problem on line 3 and the rest of the script was working without the addition of line 3 but now that line 3 work it seems like the rest of it don't execute when there is a http:// or https:// in the arg1

grep -Eiq "^https?://" <<<$1 || echo 'Ce script supporte seulement les URLs commencant par https:// ou http://' && exit 1 

NOMBRE=`echo "$1" | grep -o '/' 2> /dev/null | wc -l`

NOMBRE=$((NOMBRE+1))

ITEM=`echo "$1" | cut -d '/' -f$NOMBRE 2> /dev/null` 

wget -q $1 && echo "Votre fichier a ete telecharge ici: "$PWD/$ITEM

Comment: @G0Y1M don't put code in comments. No one will read it, especially when it's been butchered completely by the terrible formatting. If it's related to the current question then edit and include the code in the question itself, otherwise open another question. And don't use line numbers here, no one knows where line 3 is. Put a comment on that line to show it

Answer (score 1):

If you need case insensitive match

```sh
shopt -s nocasematch
if [[ ! "$1" =~ ^https?:// ]]
then
    echo 'ERROR' >&2
fi
```

Comment: `grep` can do case-insensitive matches, too, but I would still prefer this over `grep` regardless of how case should be handled.